# Slick2D+Kryonet - Client gets connected but packet was never received

Tags: java, networking, multiplayer, slick2d, kryonet

Im devloping a game to learn the basics of making online games. Though, it didnt go as well as I hoped. From what it looks like its the client not receiving the packet for some reason. As said in the title I am using Kryonet and Slick2D.

What happens is my player never gets drawn as the player list doesnt get updated.

I been looking at documentation for both and countless example. I cannot seem to find my mistake.

The Servercode:

```
package main;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.newdawn.slick.AppGameContainer;
import org.newdawn.slick.BasicGame;
import org.newdawn.slick.GameContainer;
import org.newdawn.slick.Graphics;
import org.newdawn.slick.SlickException;

import com.esotericsoftware.kryonet.Server;

import lookup.Settings;
import networking.NListener;
import networking.Network;
import structs.Player;

public class ServerMain extends BasicGame{

    /*
     * Server = Our public server object.
     * Players = A list containing all players coords and connection ID.
    */
    public static Server server;
    public static List<Player>players = new ArrayList<Player>();


    /* Our Constructor to set up our server and game.  */
    public ServerMain() throws IOException{
        super(Settings.Title);

        /*We register our kryos and our server.*/
        server = new Server();
        Network.register(server);

        /*We init our listener*/
        server.addListener(new NListener());

        /*Binding and starting the server*/
        server.bind(Settings.tcport, Settings.udport);
        server.start();
    }

    public void render(GameContainer arg0, Graphics g) throws SlickException {
        //Test for now to see if players actually do connect.
        g.drawString("Players connected:"+Integer.toString(players.size()), 10, 100);
    }

    public void init(GameContainer arg0) throws SlickException {}
    public void update(GameContainer arg0, int arg1) throws SlickException {}


    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
        //Basic slick2d stuff we set our display non fullscreen and our title from our settings.
        try{
            AppGameContainer appgc;
            appgc = new AppGameContainer(new ServerMain());
            appgc.setDisplayMode(400, 400, false);
            appgc.start();
        }catch(SlickException e){
            System.out.println("error");
        }
    }
}
```

Server NListener:

```
package networking;

import com.esotericsoftware.kryonet.Connection;
import com.esotericsoftware.kryonet.Listener;

import lookup.Settings;
import main.ServerMain;
import networking.Network.*;
import structs.Player;

public class NListener extends Listener{

    @Override
    /*Connected is called when a client is connected*/
    public void connected (Connection c) {

        //We make a new player instance.
        Player newPly = new Player();

        //Setting it to the starting position cuz we have no saving so far :)
        newPly.x = Settings.startX;
        newPly.y = Settings.startY;
        newPly.c = c;

        //We add our newly made player to the list.
        ServerMain.players.add(newPly);

        //make an instance of an updateList packet
        UpdateList outpck = new UpdateList();

        //Putting our list into the newly made packet
        outpck.players = ServerMain.players;

        //Send said paceket to all clients.
        ServerMain.server.sendToAllTCP(outpck);
    }

    @Override
    public void disconnected (Connection c) {
        //TODO: find where connection is in list and then delete that
    }

    @Override
    public void received(Connection c, Object o){
        //TODO: act upon a moving client.
    }
}
```

The client:

```
package main;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.newdawn.slick.AppGameContainer;
import org.newdawn.slick.BasicGame;
import org.newdawn.slick.GameContainer;
import org.newdawn.slick.Graphics;
import org.newdawn.slick.SlickException;
import org.newdawn.slick.tiled.TiledMap;

import com.esotericsoftware.kryonet.Client;
import lookup.Settings;
import networking.NListener;
import networking.Network;
import structs.Player;


public class BaseGame extends BasicGame{
    /*
     * CurrMap = is the current map to display
     * players = a list of players to draw.
     * client = our client object.
     * drawStr = a test string I draw to test my code (:
     * */

    public TiledMap currmap;
    public static List<Player>players = new ArrayList<Player>();
    public Client client;
    public String drawStr = "nothing yet";


    /*Our constructor to init both game and client*/
    public BaseGame(String title) {
        super(title);

        //initing our client
        client = new Client();
        client.start();

        //Registering our classes and adding our listener
        Network.register(client);
        client.addListener(new NListener());


        //Lets try connect :)
        try{
            client.connect(Settings.timeout, Settings.IP, Settings.tcport, Settings.udport);

        } catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void render(GameContainer gc, Graphics g) throws SlickException {

        //Render our map. at 0,0
        currmap.render(0, 0);

        //Lets go through all players and draw them.
        for (int i = 0; i < players.size(); i++) {
            Player Tref = players.get(i);
            g.fillRect(Tref.x*Settings.tileSize, Tref.y*Settings.tileSize, Settings.tileSize, Settings.tileSize);
        }

        //this is more for testing to see if player got updated or not.
        g.drawString(Integer.toString(players.size()), 10, 100);
        g.drawString(drawStr, 10, 120);

        g.drawString(players.toString(), 10, 350);
    }

    //Initing our tiled map
    public void init(GameContainer arg0) throws SlickException {
        currmap = new TiledMap("res/maptest.tmx");
    }

    public void update(GameContainer arg0, int arg1) throws SlickException {
        //TODO: Update players.
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){

        //Basic slick2d stuff we set our display non fullscreen and our title from our settings.
        try{
            AppGameContainer appgc;
            appgc = new AppGameContainer(new BaseGame(Settings.Title));
            appgc.setDisplayMode(400, 400, false);
            appgc.start();
        }catch(SlickException e){
            System.out.println("error");
        }
    }
}
```

Client NListener:

```
package networking;

import com.esotericsoftware.kryonet.Connection;
import com.esotericsoftware.kryonet.Listener;

import main.BaseGame;
import networking.Network.UpdateList;

public class NListener extends Listener{

    /*
     * This is our network listener.
     * Here we handle our receive functions and cleaning up after ourselves :)
     */

    @Override
    public void connected(Connection c){

    }

    @Override
    public void received (Connection connection, Object object) {
        if (object instanceof Network.UpdateList) {
            UpdateList inpck = new UpdateList();

            inpck = (UpdateList)object;
            BaseGame.players = inpck.players;
        }
    }
}
```

Common network class:

```
package networking;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo;
import com.esotericsoftware.kryonet.EndPoint;

import structs.Player;

public class Network {

    static public void register(EndPoint Ep){

        //Getting the client kryo
        Kryo kryo = Ep.getKryo();

        //Register our classes
        kryo.register(UpdateList.class);
    }

    /*
     * Updatelist is for updating list at client.
     * 
     * */
    static public class UpdateList {public List<Player>players = new ArrayList<Player>();}
}
```

Comment: new Thread(client).start();  Try this. Read https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/kryonet-users/QTHiVmqljgE

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce your problem but it's working for me.
You can try this code, which is basically yours except for some stuff:
If packages are received the server console window will print out "connected".
Client console window will print out "test".
If this is not working for you I assume that either your machine/network settings or some part of your other project is responsible for messing things up for you.

```
package stack;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.newdawn.slick.AppGameContainer;
import org.newdawn.slick.BasicGame;
import org.newdawn.slick.GameContainer;
import org.newdawn.slick.Graphics;
import org.newdawn.slick.SlickException;
import org.newdawn.slick.tiled.TiledMap;

import com.esotericsoftware.kryonet.Client;


public class BaseGame extends BasicGame{
public TiledMap currmap;
public static List<Player>players = new ArrayList<Player>();
public Client client;
public String drawStr = "nothing yet";


/*Our constructor to init both game and client*/
public BaseGame(String title) {
    super(title);

    //initing our client
    client = new Client();
    client.start();

    //Registering our classes and adding our listener
    Network.register(client);
    client.addListener(new NListener2());


    //Lets try connect :)
    try{
        client.connect(5000, "localhost", 55555, 55556);

    } catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public void render(GameContainer gc, Graphics g) throws SlickException {

    //Render our map. at 0,0

    //Lets go through all players and draw them.
    for (int i = 0; i < players.size(); i++) {
        Player Tref = players.get(i);
    }

    //this is more for testing to see if player got updated or not.
    g.drawString(Integer.toString(players.size()), 10, 100);
    g.drawString(drawStr, 10, 120);

    g.drawString(players.toString(), 10, 350);
    }

//Initing our tiled map
public void init(GameContainer arg0) throws SlickException {
   }

public void update(GameContainer arg0, int arg1) throws SlickException {
    //TODO: Update players.
    }

public static void main(String[] args){

    //Basic slick2d stuff we set our display non fullscreen and our title from our settings.
    try{
        AppGameContainer appgc;
        appgc = new AppGameContainer(new BaseGame("yo23"));
        appgc.setDisplayMode(400, 400, false);
        appgc.start();
    }catch(SlickException e){
        System.out.println("error");
    }
 }
 }
```

-

```
package stack;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo;
import com.esotericsoftware.kryonet.EndPoint;


  public class Network {

 static public void register(EndPoint Ep){

    //Getting the client kryo
    Kryo kryo = Ep.getKryo();

    //Register our classes
    kryo.register(String.class);
}

/*
 * Updatelist is for updating list at client.
 * 
 * */
  static public class UpdateList {public List<Player>players = new                      ArrayList<Player>();}
  }
```

-

```
  package stack;
  import com.esotericsoftware.kryonet.Connection;
  import com.esotericsoftware.kryonet.Listener;


  public class NListener extends Listener{

 @Override
 /*Connected is called when a client is connected*/
public void connected (Connection c) {

    //We make a new player instance.
    Player newPly = new Player();

    //Setting it to the starting position cuz we have no saving so far :)

    //We add our newly made player to the list.
    ServerMain.players.add(newPly);
    System.out.println("connected");

    //make an instance of an updateList packet

    //Putting our list into the newly made packet

    //Send said paceket to all clients.
    ServerMain.server.sendToAllTCP("test");
  }

@Override
public void disconnected (Connection c) {
    //TODO: find where connection is in list and then delete that
   }

@Override
public void received(Connection c, Object o){
    //TODO: act upon a moving client.
   }
   }
```

-

```
package stack;
import com.esotericsoftware.kryonet.Connection;
import com.esotericsoftware.kryonet.Listener;

 public class NListener2 extends Listener{


@Override
public void connected(Connection c){

 }

@Override
public void received (Connection connection, Object object) {
    if (object instanceof String) {
        String temp = (String)object;
        System.out.println(temp);
    }
 }
 }
```

-

```
 package stack;

 import java.io.IOException;
 import java.util.ArrayList;
 import java.util.List;

 import org.newdawn.slick.AppGameContainer;
 import org.newdawn.slick.BasicGame;
 import org.newdawn.slick.GameContainer;
 import org.newdawn.slick.Graphics;
 import org.newdawn.slick.SlickException;

 import com.esotericsoftware.kryonet.Server;


 public class ServerMain extends BasicGame{

/*
 * Server = Our public server object.
 * Players = A list containing all players coords and connection ID.
*/
public static Server server;
public static List<Player>players = new ArrayList<Player>();


/* Our Constructor to set up our server and game.  */
public ServerMain() throws IOException{
    super("yo");

    /*We register our kryos and our server.*/
    server = new Server();
    Network.register(server);

    /*We init our listener*/
    server.addListener(new NListener());

    /*Binding and starting the server*/
    server.bind(55555, 55556);
    server.start();
}

public void render(GameContainer arg0, Graphics g) throws SlickException {
    //Test for now to see if players actually do connect.
    g.drawString("Players connected:"+Integer.toString(players.size()), 10, 100);
 }

public void init(GameContainer arg0) throws SlickException {}
public void update(GameContainer arg0, int arg1) throws SlickException {}


public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
    //Basic slick2d stuff we set our display non fullscreen and our title from our settings.
    try{
        AppGameContainer appgc;
        appgc = new AppGameContainer(new ServerMain());
        appgc.setDisplayMode(400, 400, false);
        appgc.start();
    }catch(SlickException e){
        System.out.println("error");
    }
  }
  }
```